# Converting a class containing a hashmap of non-primitive keys or values to Json

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson, runtimetypeadapterfactory

I want to convert a class which contains a Hashmap of non-primitive keys or values to Json using Gson.
 so I realize that Hashmap keys and values are stored only as Strings when serializing with Gson. so I can't serialize them. I ran into this [solution](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java) which should be fine, but I get this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper
  location: class TypeAdapters.MapTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter<K,V>
```

any idea?

**EDIT:**

this is my code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        GameController gameController = new GameController();
        
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(gameController));
    }
}


class GameController
{
    HashMap<Tile, TileState> map = new HashMap<>();

    public GameController()
    {
        map.put(new Tile(), TileState.VISIBLE);
        map.put(new Tile(), TileState.REVEALED);
    }
}

class Tile 
{

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}

enum TileState
{
    REVEALED,
    VISIBLE
}
```

and the output is:

```
{
  "map": {
    "dir.Tile@6996db8": "REVEALED",
    "dir.Tile@368102c8": "VISIBLE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Gson can handle serializing of map. Show more details of your code.

Comment: It can handle only serializing of primitive types. Suppose that the keys are a custom object. Then the serialized keys are toString() of that custom object. That's the problem!

Comment: please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What do you want the JSON to look like? There is no data in the `Tile` class to serialize?

Comment: I don't want the keys to be tiles' address in memory like "dir.Tile@6996db8". I mean I don't want their toString(). in this way, how is Gson supposed to deserialize it?

Comment: Ok but what should be there instead?

Comment: Maybe
{ tile fields } : "tileFeature" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ran into this [solution](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/MapTypeAdapterFactory.java) which should be fine, but I get this error:
>
> ```
> java: cannot find symbol
>
>  symbol:   class TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper
>  location: class TypeAdapters.MapTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter<K,V>
> ```
>
> any idea?

`MapTypeAdapterFactory` is an internal Gson class; you should not copy its source to your project because:

1. In case bugs are found in that class and fixed in the Gson project, your copy would still contain those bugs
2. This internal class itself depends on other internal classes, in this case `TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper`, which is why you are seeing this compilation error

Instead, try to use the functionality Gson provides out-of-the-box. The [User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Maps-Examples) explains how `Map` serialization works and how you can customize it. Unfortunately due to legacy reasons Gson uses `toString()` for serialization. There are a few possible solutions:

1. Override `toString()` to return a more reasonable representation, and register a [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which handles deserialization
2. Only register a `TypeAdapter` which handles both serialization and deserialization, and use [`GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization())
3. Only use `GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`. In that case Gson will use reflection to serialize and deserialize `Tile` instances

---

Also, as side note: Your `Tile` class looks a bit incorrect:

- Normally when using a class as key of a `Map` you override `equals` and `hashCode`; otherwise instances are compared by reference equality only, and separate instances with the same field values are not considered equal
- When overriding `hashCode()` you normally also override `equals(Object)`
- Just calling `super.hashCode()` in your `hashCode()` implementation has no special effect and behaves the same way as if you had not overridden the method